# Identity Matrix and Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Hey is there a way to proof if I is the identity Matrix and P is the projection of some subspace U with $R^{nxn}$ that $I - P$ is the projection Matrix of the orthogonal subspace $U^⊥$.

Ok I know this:

$A^T*B = 0$

so I can write this:

$B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T = I - A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

is that the right approach:
$B*B^{-1}(B^T)^{-1}B^T = I - A*A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}A^T$

Comment: Yes, there is. But why don't you start by telling us your thoughts on the problem, and why you cannot prove it yourself? That'll let us better target our help to you. (You can add your current work by clicking "edit" under your problem's statement.)

Comment: I dont know how to start how can I proof I-P is the P of the orthogonal complement projection

Comment: You've written $A = U$, but this doesn't make sense: $U$ is a subspace, and $A$ is a matrix. I think your next step may be to go back and check that you understand the difference between these things. I also think that there's a word missing in your statement of the problem (it should be "$P$ is the *orthogonal* projection"); you might want to check that. (If "orthogonal" is not in there, then the problem-statement is broken, as Fred's example shows.)

Comment: sry i changed it, is this now the right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true if $P$ is symmetric. In this case we have $Im(P)=U$ and $Im(I-P)=U^{\perp}.$

Reason: $Im(I-P)= ker (P).$

Comment: what is Im and should P be always symmetric because it is the projection matrix

Comment: $Im(P)$ is the range of $P$. Let $P=A = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 &  1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right].$ Then $P^2=P$, but $P$ is not symmetric.